# May someone please suggest EHA design procedures for AFS?

Tags: control-surfaces, hydraulic-system, flutter

Are usual electro-hydraulic actuator designs for aileron control employable for aeroelastic flutter suppression? If not, where can I find design procedures for this specific case?

Answer (score 2):

This [1986 USAF experiment](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a176148.pdf) might help.

> The purpose of this test was to demonstrate in flight for the first time the
>   feasibility of powering a primary flight control surface with an
>   electromechanical actuator (EMA) in place of the standard hydromechanical
>   actuation system. An advanced development model model EMA drove the left aileron
>   on a specially modified C-141A aircraft and was to duplicate the functions of the
>   standard hydromechanical unit. Lockheed-Georgia Co. (GeLac) was the prime
>   contractor with Sundstrand Corp. as the subcontractor.
>
> [...]
>
> The C-141 aileron is statically and dynamically stable with
>   the critical flutter parameters being tip weight and actuator stiffness. If
>   either parameter were not present, the damping would still be sufficient within
>   the aircraft normal operating envelope. Laboratory studies had shown that the
>   stiffness or spring rate of the EMA was identical to the hydraulic unit. All
>   else remaining unchanged, the structural damping of the modified aircraft was
>   expected to be the same as that of the baseline aircraft. The baseline aircraft
>   has a flutter margin more than 20% above the normal operating limitations of the
>   C-141A, and well above the military specification (MILSPEC) requirements.

[image]

Comment: Is this EHA design also fit for flutter suppression? I see it is only designed to have a hydraulic stiffness sufficient to avoid flutter within the design envelope. Is this a sufficient condition for it to be fit also for active flutter suppression?